# How to add ' in NSString in ios sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsstring

I have a NSString like this

```
NSString *mystring = @"RahulVyas";
```

Now I want to add  this **'** so the new string would be `'RahulVyas'`

How to do this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
NSString *newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"'%@'", mystring];
```

Comment: where do it show this?  Have you tried outputing newString through NSLog?  Some context would help here.

Comment: The slashes don't show up in my NSLog output, I'm afraid.  Can you provide some context so we can debug?

Answer (score 0):

You just want to surround the string with single quotes, right? You can just use stringWithFormat:

```
mystring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"'%@'", mystring];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *mystring=@"'RahulVyas'";
NSLog(@"%@", mystring);
```

Seems to work just fine for me.